# Google Analytics discrepancies

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have google analytics report for goal completions which is different from what i see from BigQuery. I am using below query to get the goal completions. discrepancy is very low varies from 1 to 20 approximately.

```
SELECT
    distinct visitId
FROM
    `gcp_project.ganalytics.ga_sessions_*` AS sessions,
    UNNEST(hits) AS hits
WHERE
    regexp_contains(hits.page.pagepath, '/booking/complete*')
    and _table_suffix = '20210424'
    and totals.visits=1
```

gcp_project is in US Region and Goals report is based on france webpage. Does timezone makes the difference?

Comment: Have you tried to combine fullVisitorId and visitId instead of just visitId? is the output different? Also how is the discrepancy less or more? Is it consistent?

Comment: it is very less varies between 1 and 20.

Comment: did you tried to update your visitId?

Comment: I hope you meant to use union all between visitorid and fullvisitorId. Yes i did but count has been grown drastically. 95%+ higher than expected values. I tried select distinct(visitorid) from (select visitiorid from <tablename and where clause as above> union all select fullvisitorid from <tablename and where clause as above>)

Answer (score 0):

1. Timezone is one factor. The BigQuery export dataset will be in UTC whereas in the GA UI, the timezone is user defined for each property.
2. In GA UI, the count is an approximation done using [HyperLogLog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) functions whereas in your BigQuery query, you are doing a regular COUNT DISTINCT. An equivalent in BigQuery would be to use [Approximate aggregate functions in Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions). However, even then you might have minor discrepancies due to the different implementation of HyperLogLog in GA and BigQuery.